# start activity from custom dialog in android sdk 11 or higher

Tags: android, dialog

I have a problem and I am very confiused. I have a Dialog that it contains a Button.
I show the dialog in main Activity with this code, so simple:

```
InfoDialog id=new InfoDialog(this);
id.show();
```

and I want when I click on Button, it starts the second activity. you see it is so easy, I use this code:

```
public class InfoDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    Context context;

    public InfoDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.infodialog);
        this.context=context;
        setupViews();
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);    
    } 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent newintent= new Intent(context,DestActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(newintent);
            break;  
    }
}
```

and I declare the destAct in Manifest too. when I run it on Gingerbread Android an older sdk versions it works fine. but when I run this code on ice cream sandwich (sdk 11) or higher it gives me force close!!!

this is my log cat:

```
08-27 09:38:54.540: W/dalvikvm(10945): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3d1f8)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at my.app.InfoDialog.onClick(InfoDialog.java:131)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
08-27 09:38:54.544: E/AndroidRuntime(10945):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what the hell is this? please help me guys

Comment: pls clarify this: "I click on Button the second it starts the second activity" and show us your logcat results.

Comment: @Deadlock. post edited my friend. tnx for ur comment

Comment: @srikanth. i added my log cat

Comment: Do you have `PreferenceManager` related code? It seems the problem

Comment: wats the point of calling context.startActivity(); try to call it startActivity(intent); in onclick method

Comment: @iturki: i had PreferenceManager but i remove it. this is old log cat. sorry. that line is removed now

Comment: @deadlock: startActivity does not work in Dialog witout context

Comment: @aTa It is NOT removed yet! Did you update the question?

Comment: Before calling new activity jest close the dialog.

Comment: @aTa could you post info dialog's code(xml)?

Comment: @sirkanth: i try it but dowsnt work

Comment: i solve it guys i cant believe it but finallly after 2day i solve it. thanks all of you. i use a handler and put the newintent code in the handler's handleMessage procedure. and in button click event just i send a message to my handler. my code working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i fix it. i used a handler and write startActivity codes on handler message receive. and in button's onClick method just i sent a message to my handler. and it works fine on sdk>11. but i still dont now why my old code didnt work ;)

Answer (score 0):

the main problem lies in declaring your `Button`, that is not how you give memory to your button in your dialog, you should first get the reference of the parent(i.e. dialog over here) and after that you should find the view

For your better understanding I have Recreated your Class in the following manner, please try this and let me know

```
     Context context;
View parentView; // THIS IS ADDED

public InfoDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    parentView=setContentView(R.layout.infodialog); //UPDATED
    this.context=context;
    setupViews();
}


private void setupViews() {
    Button button=(Button)parentView.findViewById(R.id.button1); //UPDATED
    button.setOnClickListener(this);    
}
```

Comment: After modifying this you wont be getting a null pointer exception(as you button couldn't find its correct reference it got the null pointer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more simple sol:

And i didn't use the context.startActivity()   ;)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowCustomDialog);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Some Title");

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("custom dialog");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.dialogButtonOK:
                        Intent newintent= new Intent(context,OtherActivity.class);
                        startActivity(newintent);
                        break; 
                    }
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }

    });

}
```

}

Here is my xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFF" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" Ok "
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

And in OtherActivity i just showed a toast i.e:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(this, "ok working fine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Try this, its very neat, clean and self explanatory code. Keep things simple as far you can...

Deadlock...